# Change videoview frame in AVCam

Tags: ios, avcam, ios-camera, avplayerlayer

I used AVCam version of 3.1. I set the video gravity `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`. Then i want to change frame

```
- (void)setSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session
{
   ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
   [((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]) setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 240)];
   [(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[self layer] setSession:session];
}
```

But when i run the project, video frame is not change or it has a different frame size.
I found  `videoRect`object in AVCam . But this object property is readonly, i can not set it. 
How can i solve this problem ?